# Discord bot not leaving voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a problem I am using discord.js to play music but my bot does not leave the voice channel when I send a command $stop,
Please help!

```js
case 'stop':
            var server = servers[message.guild.id];
            if(message.guild.voiceConnection){
                for(var i = server.queue.length -1; i<=0; i--){
                    server.queue.splice(i, 1);
                }

                server.dispatcher.end();
                client.leaveVoiceChannel(message.member.voiceState.channelID);
                message.channel.send('Leaving the channel!')
            }

            if(message.guild.connection) message.guild.voiceConnection.disconnect();
        break;
```

Comment: What code did you try that did not work?

Comment: wait I will update my question!

Comment: should `if(message.guild.connection)` be `if(message.guild.voiceConnection)` ?

Comment: I tried using  `if(message.guild.voiceConnection)` but it did not work for me!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:- use

```js
message.member.voice.channel.leave();
```